# WordPress, duplicating plugin or a better suggestion?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, portfolio

I need a help that will solve a big problem. I'm using this nice plug in on a website: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/awesome-filterable-portfolio/

The plugin works nicely but the problem is: I only can add 1 portfolio to my website; instead I need to have two different portfolios in two different pages. I was tryng to duplicate the plugin, changing funcions name but it probably has an issue with the database which collecting data. The plugin doesn't seem hard to fix for my needs but I'm not that good with php and javascript.

Any suggestion and help will be much appreciated...thanx a lot.

Bruno

Answer (score 2):

Check this out maybe it fits your needs: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-portfolio/

Comment: @PeterSmith The plugin you linked is nice Peter, but it's not filterable. I will use that as a simple product page so my purpose is to have it sortable by category